# Webpack build gives javascript memory heap error

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript, webpack, compiler-optimization

I have my Webpack configuration as follows for a NodeJS project with TypeScript. When it is compiling it gives the "JavaScript memory Heap" error in the terminal. I usually increase the memory limit in the local terminal in order to do have the output build folder. But this is not the case with the server as it has some memory limitations. Can someone help me to sort out this issue either with the parallel build or any memory optimization technics.

This is my package.json.

```
"devDependencies": {
        "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
        "glob": "^8.0.3",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "ts-loader": "^9.4.1",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^4.9.3",
        "webpack": "^5.75.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.0",
        "zip-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.109",
        "@types/tedious": "^4.0.9",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1257.0",
        "axios": "^1.2.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "node-tls": "^0.10.2",
        "sequelize": "^6.28.0",
        "tedious": "^15.1.2"
    }
```

`as per the above dependencies I use Webpack 5.`

`This is the Webpack.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require("path");
const glob = require("glob");
const ZipPlugin = require("zip-webpack-plugin");
const tedious = require("tedious");
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

const entries = () => {
  const src = path.resolve(__dirname, "functions");
  const files = glob.sync(src + "/**/*");
  return files
    .filter((f) => f.indexOf("index.ts") > -1)
    .map((f) => "./" + path.relative(path.resolve(__dirname), f));
};

const getBundleName = (path) =>
  path
    .substring("./functions/".length, path.lastIndexOf("/"))
    .replaceAll("/", "-")
    .toLowerCase();

const config = () => {
  let modules = [];
  const files = entries();
  files.forEach((f) => {
    console.log(f)
    const bundleName = getBundleName(f);

    const outputPath = path.resolve(
      __dirname,
      "dist/" +
        bundleName.substring(0, bundleName.lastIndexOf("-")) +
        "/" +
        bundleName.substring(bundleName.lastIndexOf("-") + 1)
    );

    const moduleConfig = {
      name: bundleName,
      entry: f,
      output: {
        path: outputPath,
        filename: "index.js",
        libraryTarget: "commonjs",
        clean: true,
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.ts?$/,
            use: "ts-loader",
            exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.test.ts?$/],
          },
        ],
      },
      target: "node",
      plugins: [
        new ZipPlugin({
          path: "./",
          filename: `${bundleName}.zip`,
        }),
        new webpack.ids.DeterministicChunkIdsPlugin({
          maxLength: 5,
        }),
      ],
      optimization: {
        minimizer: [
          new TerserPlugin({
            parallel: true,           
          }),
        ],
        chunkIds: 'named',
        concatenateModules: true,
        emitOnErrors: true,
        mangleWasmImports: true,
        moduleIds: 'deterministic',
        runtimeChunk: {
          name: 'runtime',
        },
        sideEffects: 'flag',
        usedExports: 'global',
      },
      resolve: {
        mainFields: ["main"],
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".json", "..."],
        alias: {'tedious': path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/tedious')},
      },
      resolveLoader: {
        modules: ["node_modules"],
      },
      externals: ['pg', 'sqlite3', 'tedious', 'pg-hstore'],
      /*devtool: "source-map",*/
    };

    modules.push(moduleConfig);
  });

  return modules;
};

module.exports = config();
```

I am expecting to understand the issues or any improvements of my Webpack configuration for the memory optimization for the code build with this nodejs TS project.

Answer (score 0):

if you hit **heap out of memory** with **webpack** – give it more memory with
this kind of syntax:

`node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/.bin/webpack`